# Gdal+Geos point in polygon test fails under MinGW64

Tags: gdal, ogr, point-in-polygon, geos

I have to build a grid of points and remove the points that falls inside a polygon.
Polygons are defined in a ESRI shapefile, points are in a list.

This is how I make the test:

```
OGRLayer *layer = mShapefile->GetLayer(lr);
layer->ResetReading();
layer->SetSpatialFilter(&point); //getting only the feature intercepting the point
OGRFeature *ftr;
while (( ftr = layer->GetNextFeature()) != 0) {
    if (point.Within(ftr->GetGeometryRef())) {
         n.good = false;
         break;
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly on Linux (Ubuntu 14.10, GDAL 1.11).

I had to recompile the library under MinGW64, first I forgot to compile with GEOS and the Within() call always returned false (as defined in the API).

If I compile with GEOS, the result is apparently a random response - some point outside the polygon set is filtered out, other inside are accepted.

Is there any known issue, or workaround, or maybe did I forget some other required library for gdal to work properly?

In a previous version I was only testing for results of GetNextFeature(), and it worked perfectly under linux. Under MinGW I found the same strange result.

Comment: It seems the build is broken. I am not sure why it happened, I suspect some dependency is badly screwed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build is broken. After a long debugging, I found out that if PROJ4 isn't compiled before gdal, the resulting library will NOT work correctly with different reference spaces.